# List JSON array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a php (history.php) that creates a json

```
$i=1;
 $q=mysql_query("select * from participants where phone='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['phone'])."' limit 10");
 while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
      $response[$i] = $rs['code'];
$i++;   
    }
    print json_encode($response);
    exit;
```

In js I access this file:

```
var req=$.get("history.php", { phone: "" + phone + ""},

                        function(data) {
        //data="1":"code1","2":"code2","3":"code3","4":"code4","5":"code5"};
                            var msg = "";
                            for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
                                msg+= "<li>"+data[i];
                            }
                            $(form_message).html(msg);

                        })
```

After this code is executed my output is

"

1

"

:

"

which means that 'data' is not passed as an array.. it's passed like a string.
But if I uncomment the data var in js everything is ok.
The output is:

code1

code2

code3

code4

code5

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong when passing the data from php.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

As in your case returned content is interpreted as `text`, not as `json`, you need to use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of `$.get`:

```
var req=$.getJSON("history.php", { phone: "" + phone + ""}, function(data) {
    var msg = "";
    for(var i in data){
        msg+= "<li>"+data[i]+"</li>";
    }
    $(form_message).html(msg);
});
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Thanks very much.  Could you also please tell me how to determine the length of data... I've tried data.length  but returns undefined:(

Comment: @MihaiStancioiu What do you mean, by '`length`'?  The amount of keys(e.g. 1,2,3,4,5) in data object?

Comment: @MihaiStancioiu I think,you don't need it...Use `for in` to interate through all elements of `data`, instead of `for`.See my update.